# Союз "а" может быть в роли детерминанта?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, морфология, союзы

Так был заведено в те времена. *А старшего брата благословлял отец и его должны были слушаться другие братья*.

- Можно ли вообще всё, что стоит вначале предложения, считать детерминантом и на этом основании не ставить запятую между частями сложного предложения? И в общем, насколько *обязательно* выделять детерминант. А если, например, мы не сможем определить, что перед нами детерминант и поставим запятую, то это будет ошибкой? Например, здесь: **С тех пор** всё там устроилось, и предприятие процветало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще-то детерминант - это член предложения, относящийся ко всему составу предложения, распространяющий его в целом и не связанный ни с каким отдельным его членом. Союз не является детерминантом. Речь идёт просто об общем элементе.

У Розенталя есть примечание:

2. Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом **и** простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед **и** ставится:

   *Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, **но** ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых (П.)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

*С тех пор всё там устроилось и предприятие процветало*. - С тех пор - детерминант, общий член для двух предложений, запятой нет. Если поставим запятую, получится, что второе предложение само по себе, а ведь оно как бы вбирает в себя  это "всё устроилось", потому оно и процветало - именно с тех пор. Нарушатся причинно-следственные связи.

Изменилась мысль автора, получилось: *С тех пор всё там устроилось, и предприятие (теперь, а не с тех пор) процветало*.

Вы правы, иногда трудно увидеть оттенки смысла предложения, но если мы его не увидим - изменим мысль автора, а грамматически всё будет верно. Так что если это наше предложение, мы вольны выбрать вариант с детерминантом или без него, а если это учебное задание, мы должны понять мысль автора.